# Getting the Facebook "Safe-Image" URL after Redirect

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I'm currently working with the Facebook PHP SDK and I'm facing one little problem. For some reason, 2 out of 25 posts contain a so-called "safe-image" which basically means that Facebook isn't providing a direct URL to this image. Instead, the URL redirects to the image indirectly.

Does any know how to retrieve the URL "after" the redirect? I will post two sample images below. I have tried to achieve this with cURL - but I failed.

`https://www.facebook.com/ads/image/?d=AQKSUWuaIXz-dJmE44rETRVS0tH_wzPCCIb0oJQqB9LKNeLWUSFkJvcHYNCx0pywb4q8k6iaC9RF25kOlvgY7NCzW96myAtYf8u6Ap4gi2_CVdJ-eScWQhmB8dGbAfl1iKiR_CS1gMMxHwWWfo_nLxeZ`- "Safe Image"

`https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t31.0-8/s720x720/12698319_975185712569283_7740104395803745910_o.jpg` - "Normal Image"

Comment: you want the result in curl?

Comment: I want the result in PHP basically. I tried to retrieve the 302 URL, but it returns the following URL:

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser

Comment: What do you want to do with it? (Facebook CDN URLs should be considered transient – they can change over time, and should not be stored for long-term use.)

Comment: I'm creating a script that cronjob's certain posts so that the pageload is increased.